# hg update is taking more than an hour on a repo which has subrepos

Tags: mercurial

`hg update` on a repo (which has lot of subrepos) is taking very long (approx. 1hr) on my mac.  It used to be not like this.  Repos with no sub-repos it is fast.  For some reason I started seeing this behavior recently.

I updated mercurial to latest version (5.0.1) and still see the same issue.

To get away from this issue, I started using docker to do the `hg up` on the repo.  It is faster that way.  I still don't understand why it is slow on mac.

Comment: Are you running inside a VM on your Mac? If so, are you using a shared folder in your VM? If so, that's probably the reason: shared folders sometimes have terrible behavior.

Comment: I am using Mac and no shared folders.

Comment: Does it consume CPU time? Does it use network bandwidth? Do you see if it is a specific subrepo that takes so long?

Comment: I can definitely monitor CPU and network bandwidth.  How will I know which subrepo is taking longer?

Comment: Run hg up -v. It generated enough output for you to know which one it is working on.